# How to interpret browser wait time in browser snapshot

Tags: javascript, performance, browser, navigation, performance-testing

I am doing website performance monitoring and optimization.
When you look at navigation timing API there are many wait time between diffrent segment of a single page request.

Image:https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webperf/raw-file/tip/specs/NavigationTiming/timing-overview.png
        The below metrics we are getting navigation timing API.
        {
            navigationStart,
            unloadEventStart,
            unloadEventEnd,
            redirectStart,
            redirectEnd,
            fetchStart,
            domainLookupStart,
            domainLookupEnd,
            connectStart,
            connectEnd,
            secureConnectionStart,
            requestStart,
            responseStart,
            responseEnd,
            domLoading,
            domInteractive,
            domContentLoadedEventStart,
            domContentLoadedEventEnd,
            domComplete,
            loadEventStart,
            loadEventEnd
        }
        On computing the metrics we get the wait time on each segments.In that 

        Wait time before Redirection - diff(navigationStart, redirectStart)
        Wait time after Redirection - diff(redirectEnd, fetchStart)
        Wait time before DNS - diff(fetchStart, domainLookupStart)
        Wait time before TCP - diff(domainLookupEnd, connectStart)
        Wait time after TCP - diff(connectEnd, requestStart)
        Wait time after Response - diff(responseEnd, domLoading)

        Can anyone explain what work done by browser during each wait time of above mentioned.
        What are all the significant factors influenced to increase and decrease in wait time.

        Refrence: https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webperf/raw-file/tip/specs/NavigationTiming/Overview.html#process

Comment: I also experienced a significant value (~400ms) of `diff(redirectEnd, fetchStart)`